# Mathematica region of parameters with roots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am currently trying to obtain an analytical expression for a range of validity of an expression. I am doing this with reduce in Mathematica but it keeps giving me the expression in terms of the Roots function. I tried to solve it and these roots have analytical solutions, is there any way to get a cleaner expression, preferably in terms of the parameters only and no root function.

Code:

```
    FullSimplify[Reduce[{-((6 \[Alpha]^4 + 21 \[Alpha]^3 \[Lambda] + 27 \[Alpha]^2 \[Lambda]^2 + 15 \[Alpha] \[Lambda]^3 + 3 \[Lambda]^4 + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-(\[Alpha] + \[Lambda])^6 (-72 + 16 \[Alpha]^3 \[Lambda] + 21 \[Lambda]^2 + 4 \[Alpha] \[Lambda] (-9 + 4 \[Lambda]^2) + 4 \[Alpha]^2 (-15 + 8 \[Lambda]^2))])/( 4 (\[Alpha] + \[Lambda])^4)) < 0 && -((6 \[Alpha]^4 + 21 \[Alpha]^3 \[Lambda] + 27 \[Alpha]^2 \[Lambda]^2 + 15 \[Alpha] \[Lambda]^3 +  3 \[Lambda]^4 - Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-(\[Alpha] + \[Lambda])^6 (-72 + 16 \[Alpha]^3 \[Lambda] + 21 \[Lambda]^2 + 4 \[Alpha] \[Lambda] (-9 + 4 \[Lambda]^2) +4 \[Alpha]^2 (-15 + 8 \[Lambda]^2))])/( 4 (\[Alpha] + \[Lambda])^4)) < 0 && -((3 (-2 \[Beta] + \[Lambda] + \[Lambda] \[Mu]))/(\[Alpha] \
+ \[Lambda])) < 0 && \[Alpha] (\[Alpha] + \[Lambda]) > -3 && \[Lambda] \
(\[Lambda] + \[Alpha]) > 3}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Lambda], \[Mu]}, 
Reals, Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's also a stackexchange specifically for Mathematica, maybe that's a better place for this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
FullSimplify[ToRadicals[Reduce[...]]]
```

which will transform each of your `Root` objects into radicals